# windows 7 wont memorize icons size and icons order in folder

Tags: windows-7

after a damn malware,

icons of windows explorer folder are always set to one single type of view, common to every folder of my computer

before the malware, when in IE c:\myfolder i do set the "big icons" view,

closing explorer.exe,

then returning to c:\myfolder i was still viewing "big icons"... now, after the malware, the view is always reset to the "details view"

the same thing happens with the display order of the icons, if i do set "order by date", returning back in the same folder, the display order is returned back to "alphabetically order"

is there a way to restore the original functionality?

thank you in advance (and feel free to correct my english)!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following registry keys (with **) to reset your folder views

32bit Windows 7

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **BagMRU**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **Bags**
```

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\ **Bags**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\ **BagMRU**
```

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **BagMRU**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **Bags**
```

.

64bit Windows 7

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **BagMRU**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **Bags**
```

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\ **Bags**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam\ **BagMRU**
```

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **BagMRU**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **Bags**
```

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **Bags**
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Wow6432Node\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\ **BagMRU**
```

Comment: hi my friend... i've just restarted my windows, but nothing is changed, sadly, folders are still returning back to default view :(

Comment: also, i've followed this (with fixit and manually) without success http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813711

Comment: maybe I misunderstand you, if you change the view settings they do not stick when you re-open a folder?

Comment: yes :( IE, if i set arrange icons by date, this setting is not still there when i re-open the same folder

Comment: malware sucks, sometimes damage is so obscure you have to re-install the OS.